# How to kill a specific docker container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

How to kill a specific docker container using docker-compose, I have tried the below but its didn't work appreciate your help.

```
root@docker:/opt/dockercompose# docker  container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
792663a9f2de        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8005->80/tcp   dockercompose_webapp2_1
1f94ff0e70cf        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   dockercompose_webapp1_1
root@docker:/opt/dockercompose# docker-compose kill 792663a9f2de
ERROR: No such service: 792663a9f2de
root@docker:/opt/dockercompose#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command works-

```
root@docker:/opt/dockercompose# docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -p 792663a9f2de kill
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the `docker-compose` commands take the service names as specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  The `docker ps` output you show could be created from a `docker-compose.yml` file like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp1:
    image: nginx
    ports: ['8000:80']
  webapp2:
    image: nginx
    ports: ['8005:80']
```

If you want to kill off a specific Compose-managed container, you can `docker-compose kill webapp2`; it will find it in the `docker-compose.yml` and match it up with some hidden container metadata.

For most practical things, if you're in a Compose-managed environment, you can use exclusively `docker-compose` commands: `docker-compose ps` to list the containers, `docker-compose logs` to see a container's output, and so on.  All of these again take the Compose service name, not the Docker container name or ID.